# Duplicate a number within a list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have the following code:

```
def repeatNumbers(data):
    for number in data:
        return [number[0]] * number[1]
        

print(repeatNumbers([[1, 10]]))
print(repeatNumbers([[1, 2], [2, 3]]))
print(repeatNumbers([[10, 4], [34, 6], [92, 2]]))
```

I wish to duplicate the first number within the list by the value of the second number in the list. I can only obtain the following:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1]
[10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Whilst the output must be a STRING as in the following format:

```
1111111111

11, 222

10101010, 343434343434, 9292
```

Comment: What have to tried and what the issue you are having? We are not a free code-writing service.  Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to meet community standards

Comment: If you `return` inside a `for` loop, the loop will terminate. A function can return only once.

Comment: @blorgon Because 3 out of 4 answers are not helpful and 4 out of 4 do not even explain the problem that OP has.

Comment: A solution is not always helpful if it a) does not explain where the problem is and b) uses concepts OP does not understand and c) has just code without an explanation. Sorry. (I can see your post due to 10k rep)

Comment: No problem. Then you get downvotes, and when you finish editing, people might remove the downvote (if they stay long enough)

Comment: @blorgon That's called the "fasted gun in the west" approach and is discouraged. It also leads to downvotes on half-baked answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def repeatNumbers(data):
    output_strings = []
    for numbers in data:
        output_strings.append(str(numbers[0]) * numbers[1])
    return ", ".join(output_strings)
        

print(repeatNumbers([[1, 10]]))
print(repeatNumbers([[1, 2], [2, 3]]))
print(repeatNumbers([[10, 4], [34, 6], [92, 2]]))
```

prints

```
1111111111
11, 222
10101010, 343434343434, 9292
```

Instead of returning, store intermediate values (`str(numbers[0]) * numbers[1]`) in a list

Answer (score 1):

Your issue was that you were using `return` inside a `for` loop. This tells Python to *immediately* return the value you've told it to. A cleaner way to do this is cast your data as `str` and use the `str.join()` method:

```py
def repeatNumbers(data):
    return ", ".join(str(a)*b for a, b in data)
```

Output:

```py
>>> print(repeatNumbers([[1, 10]]))
1111111111
>>> print(repeatNumbers([[1, 2], [2, 3]]))
11, 222
>>> print(repeatNumbers([[10, 4], [34, 6], [92, 2]]))
10101010, 343434343434, 9292
```

The expression `(str(a)*b for a, b in data)` is what's known as a generator expression in Python. It allows for clean, compact, lazy iteration.

The `str.join()` method takes an iterable sequence of strings and joins them using the string literal used as the prefix to the `.join()` call. In other words, `", ".join(seq)` will take the sequence of strings `seq` and join them with the string `", "`.

Comment: List comprehension might also be a concept OP has never used.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks for your comments. I am running a Bootcamp prep course and some of the exercises required me to follow their way of writing code. I am aware that better code can be written but I am following their way of conducting these exercises.